# Get wrong result when using SYS_CONTEXT('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'DBA') in function of Oracle VPD

Tags: sql, database, oracle, vpd

I am using Oracle 19 and Navicat.

When I execute this, it returns TRUE.

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'DBA') FROM DUAL;
```

However, when I implement a policy to a table, using a function to control permission, in which `SYS_CONTEXT('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'DBA')` returns FALSE.

But, when I try to use `SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'SESSION_USER' )`, it returns the same user in SQL and function.

Here only the last SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''SESSION_USER'' ) works well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION show_own_salary(v_schema IN VARCHAR2, v_obj IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS condition VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
IF SYS_CONTEXT('SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'DBA') = 'TRUE' THEN
        RETURN '';
END IF;
IF SYS_CONTEXT( 'SYS_SESSION_ROLES', 'ALL_ACCOUNTANT' ) = 'TRUE' THEN
    RETURN '';
END IF;
RETURN 'SID = (SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''SESSION_USER'' ))';
END show_own_salary;
```

I executed `SELECT * FROM session_roles` and it shows below:
[roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGOKb.png)

[USER_SYS_PRIVS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3oFd.png)
[USER_ROLE_PRIVS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVwNs.png)

Comment: What other privileges are assigned to the user you tested with? Some system privileges exempt the user from VPD policies being applied.

Comment: @pmdba Hi, the user 'company' was granted connect, resource and dba. And I outputted its system and role privileges.

Comment: nobody has a privilege like EXEMPT ACCESS POLICY...